# Install and Run OpenOffice 4.1.2 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, openoffice

After installing Open Office 4.1.2 on Amazon Linux (http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#other_linux)
, I run it in the background

`soffice -headless -accept=„socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;“ -nofirststartwizard &`

When I now start a Program that relies on a running Open Office Instance, I get an

`com.sun.star.lib.loader.Loader::getCustomLoader: no UNO installation found!`

What can I do about it?

Comment: 1) don't run Amazon Linux unless you have a really good reason to do so. 2) why do you need OO installed on your server?

Comment: You're going to have to do better than that to convince us why you need to do this. At the moment, it seems as if you're using this as a workstation machine, which is off-topic here. If you can convince us otherwise, I'll gladly re-open the question.

Comment: 1) My boss told me to. The company I am working in is using Amazon Linux and I am not in the position to change that. Is this really important?

Comment: 2) On this server, a programm is running that makes use of a running open office instance and, again, I am not in a position to change that. And, again, is that important?

Comment: OK, I will re-open the question. One piece of advice: when people ask clarifying questions on SF, do not blow them off. They are trying to help. Server Fault is not an answer vending machine - it's a collaboration between question askers and question answerers, and asking clarifying questions is part of that collaboration. You don't get to just lob questions over the fence and demand an answer.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I rather felt a little offended by your questions, thats why.

Comment: You're coming and asking a question on a site that has a large number of highly-experienced linux admins. You can expect to get professional-level interaction. For the record (and I understand you can't do anything about this), using Amazon Linux is a really bad decision for many reasons. It's a poorly-supported, rarely-used platform. You would be much better off sticking with CentOS, Debian, etc.